# Python - Updating a JSON REST array

Tags: python, arrays, json, rest, stingray

I am new to Python, what I am trying to do is write a script that will take the IP address I am supplying it and updating an array that I am pulling from a JSON RESTful API. I can pull the data out of the array fine.  Here is what my code looks like so far(please excuse the look of the code)

```
import requests
import json
import sys

pool_name = sys.argv[1]
add_node = sys.argv[2]

url = 'https://<stingray RESTApi>:9070/api/tm/1.0/config/active/pools/' + pool_name
jsontype = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
client = requests.Session()
client.auth = ('<username>', '<password>')
client.verify = 0

response = client.get(url)
pools = json.loads(response.content)
nodes = pools['properties']['basic']['nodes']
```

Now I have been looking at using this

```
client.put(url, <I am stuck>, headers = jsontype)
```

At this point I have reached the limits of my current know how of Python(As I just started to learn on the last few days). I have looked at using something like this as well to get the data I have collected append to the array and then trying to PUT it.

```
updatepool['properties']['basic']['nodes'].append(add_node)
```

When I print updatepool, I see that what I am after is working but again PUTing it in the array has stumped me.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE: Here is an update to my code, getting a 400 response from the API

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests 
import json 
import sys 

pool_name = sys.argv[1]
#add_node = sys.argv[2]
add_node = u'10.10.10.1:80'

url = 'https://<uri>:9070/api/tm/1.0/config/active/pools/' + pool_name  
jsontype = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
client = requests.Session()  
client.auth = ('<username>', '<password')  
client.verify = 0  

response = client.get(url)  
pools = json.loads(response.content)
nodes = pools['properties']['basic']['nodes']
data = nodes
data.append(add_node)

print client.put(url,json.dumps(data), headers=jsontype)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs

> > > print requests.put.**doc**
> > >       Sends a PUT request. Returns :class:`Response` object.

```
:param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
:param data: (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
:param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that ``request`` takes.
```

so `client.put(url, {'key':'value'}, headers = jsontype)` 
works.

what you need to know now is what key val that url is accepting: supposing it accepts a 'node' and key you could use

```
client.put(url, {'node':add_node}, headers = jsontype)
```

or

```
client.put(url, {'node':updatepool['properties']['basic']['nodes']**[0]**}, headers = jsontype)
```

to send first node

Comment: Thanks for this, this was very helpful but I am getting a 400 response when I try to put the data back, I went with this example, client.put(url, {'node':add_node}, headers = jsontype).

Comment: I got it working, what I have to do is push the entire JSON data back, which is my pools variable. From there I can see the node get added in :)

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=session#requests.Session.put)

```
put(url, data=None, **kwargs)
     Sends a PUT request. Returns Response object.

     Parameters:    
         url – URL for the new Request object.
         data – (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the Request.
         **kwargs – Optional arguments that request takes.
```

You can give 'dict`with`list` (array).